# javax.xml.datatype.Duration to nanoseconds

Tags: java, date, duration

I have a [`javax.xml.datatype.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html) that contains a fraction of millisecond, e.g. a duration of 1.5ms (1500 microseconds):

```
Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration("PT0.0015S");
```

I need to get this value in nanoseconds but the smallest unit of time that `Duration` is providing seems to be `getTimeInMillis`, which returns a `long` and cuts of anything smaller than a millisecond.

How do I get the duration in nanoseconds?

Comment: Would it be possible that you can avoid having a `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`? I would find a `java.time.Duration` very much nicer to work with (and it accepts the same ISO 8601 syntax).

Comment: @OleV.V. I wish I could change it, but unfortunately it is part of an important third-party API :(

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the duration to [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). Then call [`toNanos()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toNanos()) method.

```
Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration("PT0.0015S");
java.time.Duration.parse(duration.toString()).toNanos();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work reliable after all. When parsing `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration("P0Y0M0DT0H0M1S").toString()`, it throws a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text cannot be parsed to a Duration`. I have the feeling this might be implementation-specific depending on the XML implementation used though.

Comment: The XML duration allows to specify years, months and days. Days are ok, but years and months do not have a fixed value. February is much shorter than March. Thus a duration only has value when you know what it is relative to. Also, adding a combined duration of days and months to date is tricky. Adding the days first might change the length of the month added. Example feb 26 2021 + 4 days and 1 month. Add month first and this becomes march 26 plus 4 days is march 30th. Add days first this becomes March 2nd (feb has 28 days in 2021) plus a month is April 2nd....

Answer (score 1):

The Duration API was *slightly* surprising to me here because you have to get the *seconds* part of the duration with [Duration.getField(Field)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html#getField(javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants.Field)). That method returns a `Number`, which is either a `BigInteger` (for days, hours, minutes. etc) or a `BigDecimal` (only for seconds).

So to get fractions of a second you can use `getField(DatatypeConstants.SECONDS)` and then convert the value:

```
Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration("PT0.0015S");
BigDecimal seconds = (BigDecimal) duration.getField(DatatypeConstants.SECONDS);
// Note that `getField` will return `null` if the field is not defined.
if(seconds != null) {
    System.out.println(seconds + "s");                    // 0.0015s
    System.out.println(seconds.movePointRight(9) + "ns"); // 1500000ns
}
```

**But these are not the total seconds of the duration.** This is only the value of the seconds *field* and other fields are ignored. For a duration like `P1M0.0015` (1 minute and 1.5 milliseconds) this would ignore the minute and would just return 1.5ms.

Converting all other fields of the duration to seconds and summing them up would work. Or by using `getTimeInMillis`, which returns the total milliseconds of the duration:

```
Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration("PT1M0.0015S");
BigDecimal seconds = (BigDecimal) duration.getField(DatatypeConstants.SECONDS);

// only keep the fractional part
BigDecimal fractionalSeconds = seconds.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);

long totalMillis = duration.getTimeInMillis(new Date(0));
// convert total millis to whole seconds (removes fractional part)
BigDecimal totalIntegerSeconds = 
    new BigDecimal(totalMillis).movePointLeft(3).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);

// add both to get total seconds 
BigDecimal totalSeconds = totalIntegerSeconds.add(fractionalSeconds);

System.out.println(totalSeconds + "s");                     // 60.0015s
System.out.println(totalSeconds.movePointRight(9) + "ns");  // 60001500000ns
```

This seems to work but is way too complicated. There must be an easier way to do this.

[@hasnae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59950502/897024) solution looks much better if you are using Java 1.8. I wonder what the API designer's intended way to get nanosecond precision was though, since `java.time.Duration` was introduced years later than `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`.